# Pandas apply a function at fixed interval

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy

Is there a straightforward existing method to apply a function at fixed interval with pandas (or numpy, scipy) ?

**Example**

A `pd.DataFrame` of length 11

```
0   0.2
1   0.3
2   0.4
3   0.4
4   0.4
5   0.4
6   0.4
7   0.4
8   0.4
9   0.4
10  0.6
```

For instance applying a min function with interval = 5 would result in

```
0   0.2 # Beginning of interval
1   0.2
2   0.2
3   0.2
4   0.2 # End of interval
5   0.4 # Beginning of interval
6   0.4
7   0.4
8   0.4
9   0.4 # End of interval
10  0.6 # Beginning of interval (takes the min function of the remaining values)
```

So far I can do it with

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col = 0, header = None) # Copying the above data
df['intervals'] = (np.arange(len(df)) / 5).astype(int)
mapper = df.groupby('intervals').min()
result = df['intervals'].apply(lambda x: mapper.loc[x])
print result
```

But I wonder if there exists fixed interval filters already built in pandas/numpy/scipy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the various possibilities would be to use [`groupby.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) after grouping them as per the necessary window interval.

When you perform `min` on the `transform` method of `groupby`, all sub-groups would get filled by the smallest value present in their respective group.

Assuming the single columned `DF` to be represented by `s`:

```
s.groupby(np.arange(len(s.index)) // 5).transform('min')
```

produces:

```
0     0.2
1     0.2
2     0.2
3     0.2
4     0.2
5     0.4
6     0.4
7     0.4
8     0.4
9     0.4
10    0.6
dtype: float64
```